# Read from one CSV and filter other rows with the same variables in another CSV

Tags: java

I used to use R for data processing and now my new project needs Java, so I apologise if I am asking naive questions. My problem is I want to achieve something like the `filter` in R dplyr. Basically, I now have two CSV files:

One is about the *person attribute*, where the first element in each row represents a unique personID:

```
1,4CC0D97F9ECC6B1A,MUTSAARD,7,m,7-8,0,0,ACT
2,F6B73020FC552E32,PORTE TERVUEREN,3,m,3-4,3,0,EMP
4,4072878C4683C96F,ALTITUDE 100,4,f,1-2,5,1,EMP
```

Another CSV is about *person activities*, where the first element in each row also represents unique personID:

```
1,0,0,0,9,34,home,34200,150101.5,176176
1,1,10,34,13,34,leisure,48600,249319.227415549,64034.2890971927
1,2,14,34,14,35,home,600,249319.227415549,64034.2890971927
1,3,15,49,16,19,shopping,58800,281683.200856897,118126.130836235
1,4,18,4,25,0,home,90000,281683.200856897,118126.130836235
2,0,0,0,15,38,home,56400,152056.679999997,170502.339842428
2,1,15,48,24,1,work,86400,153720.999999996,167515.000842442
2,2,24,18,25,0,home,90000,156685.535763012,169194.702448164
4,0,0,0,9,58,home,36000,147758.618000003,167097.459842441
4,1,10,29,14,58,work,54000,147251.000000004,174872.000842412
4,2,15,28,16,28,shopping,59400,144431.419000006,166735.039842444
4,3,16,38,18,38,leisure,67200,146053.041238428,169647.999589575
4,4,18,58,25,0,home,90000,149907.09447342,170229.096090939
```

What I want to do now is to first loop the person attribute and do some coding there, after, I would like to filter the rows with the same personID in the activities CSV and loop those rows with the same personID and do some coding there.

So the code I have for now is:

```
BufferedReader attributeReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(attributesFile));
String agent = null;
while ((agent = attributeReader.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] attributeSpilted = agent.split(",");
    int attributeAgentID = Integer.parseInt(attributeSpilted[0]);

    // Set attributes for agents
    Person person = populationFactory.createPerson(Id.createPersonId(attributeAgentID));

    // Question: What I should do here to find the activities with the same personID?

    population.addPerson(person);
}
```

The question I have is in the code, I get stuck there and unsure about what I should do here to find the activities with the same personID?

Comment: Think of the two CSV files as having a relationship based on the `attributeAgentID` so that the information you want in the second CSV is on the rows with the same `attributeAgentID`. There are different ways to go about doing this, try the simplest and slowest first to make sure you have the relationship working.

Answer (score 0):

From your code, i assume you can read the csv file and convert to DataObject by each line without problem.

So you will have 2 class: Person, PersonActivity for example.

If memory is not a problem for now, i suggest the simple way to read person activity and convert it Map.

```
// key is attributeAgentID, value List<PersonActivity>
// mean each person id have list of activities 
Map<Integer, List<PersonActivity>> getPersonActivityFromCsv(String file);
```

So you just need to update few code when processing list of person:

```
Map<Integer,List<PersonActivity>> map = getPersonActivityFromCsv("activities.csv");
...
while(...){
int attributeAgentID = Integer.parseInt(attributeSpilted[0]);

    // Set attributes for agents
    Person person = populationFactory.createPerson(Id.createPersonId(attributeAgentID));
   List<PersonActivity> activities = map.get(attributeAgentID);
   // then do something with list activities here.
 }
```

Comment: Hello Huy, thanks for the hint :) Yes, I tried to do something as you suggested but I don't know why my code is not working. I have made a new post here and I am wondering if you have any idea? Thanks :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69726459/adding-key-value-in-hashmap-by-while-loop-but-not-working

Comment: Your question is solved by others :) ...