# Adding <Key, Value> in hashmap by while loop but not working

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I have the following CSV file and I would like to create a hashmap which the unique key should be the first value of each row and value should be an `arraylist` containing the information of each line under the first value of this row. Example CSV as below:

```
1,0
1,1
1,2
1,3
1,4
2,0
2,1
2,2
4,0
10,0
10,1
10,2
10,3
10,4
10,5
```

So ideally, I would like the final ArrayList to be something like:

```
{1=[1,0, 1,1, 1,2, 1,3, 1,4], 2=[2,0, 2,1, 2,2], 4=[4,0], 10=[10,0, 10,1, 10,2, 10,3, 10,4, 10, 5]}
```

Below is the code I used trying to solve this problem by a while loop

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int activityRecord = 1;
        String activitiesFile = "scenarios/BrusselsPopulationFromR/BrusselsActivities.csv";

        HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>> idAndAllActivities = new HashMap<>();
        try {
            BufferedReader activityReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(activitiesFile));
            String agentActivity = null;
            ArrayList activities = new ArrayList();

            while ((agentActivity = activityReader.readLine()) != null){
                String activityWithAllInfo = agentActivity;
                String[] activitySpilted = agentActivity.split(",");
                int activityAgentID = Integer.parseInt(activitySpilted[0]);

                if (activityAgentID == activityRecord){
                    activities.add(activityWithAllInfo);
                } else if (activityAgentID != activityRecord){
                    idAndAllActivities.put(activityRecord, activities);
                    activityRecord = activityAgentID;
                    activities.clear();
                    activities.add(activityWithAllInfo);
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(idAndAllActivities);
    }
```

Basically, I try to justify whether `activityAgentID == activityRecord` (originally to be 1), and if it's different, I will add the <K,V> to the hashmap and clear the `activities` arrayList. However, the output of this program is something like:

```
{1=[10,0, 10,1, 10,2, 10,3, 10,4, 10,5], 2=[10,0, 10,1, 10,2, 10,3, 10,4, 10,5], 4=[10,0, 10,1, 10,2, 10,3, 10,4, 10,5]}
```

This is not what I want, and I tried to debug this but I cannot find the reason for this as I am really new to Java... I am wondering if you know how to solve this? Any hints will be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it in another way. A way that does not break if the order of the CSV file changes as follows:

```
1,0
1,1
2,0
1,2
10,0
10,1
10,2
1,3
1,4
2,1
2,2
4,0
10,3
10,4
10,5
```

With this CSV your code will fail because you are relying on the CSV file to have all `1` activity records together. In order to cope with this, try the following (notice that you are no longer relying on `activityRecord`):

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String activitiesFile = "scenarios/BrusselsPopulationFromR/BrusselsActivities.csv";

    HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>> idAndAllActivities = new HashMap<>();
    try {
        BufferedReader activityReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(activitiesFile));
        String agentActivity = null;

        while ((agentActivity = activityReader.readLine()) != null){
            String activityWithAllInfo = agentActivity;
            String[] activitySpilted = agentActivity.split(",");
            int activityAgentID = Integer.parseInt(activitySpilted[0]);

            if (idAndAllActivities.containsKey(activityAgentID)){
                ArrayList existentActivities = idAndAllActivities.get(activityAgentID);
                existentActivities.add(activityWithAllInfo);
            } else {
                ArrayList activities = new ArrayList();
                activities.add(activityWithAllInfo);
                idAndAllActivities.put(activityAgentID, activities);
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println(idAndAllActivities);
}
```

Comment: Hello João, thanks for the answer. While your code works well, I am still wondering why when using `existentActivities.add(activityWithAllInfo)`, the new value will be added to the original hashmap value which corresponds to the key ``activityAgentID``? In my understanding, you are just changing the arrayList `existentActivities`, instead of the original arrayList that in the Hashmap? Thanks :)

Comment: Hi @Jingjun, no that is not the case. Java collections are by default mutable, which means that when we do `ArrayList existentActivities = idAndAllActivities.get(activityAgentID);` we have in fact a reference to the actual list in the `HashMap`, which we can change (in your case update) to have one additional element. This was in fact the issue with your implementation. You were always changing the same `ArrayList` and thus you endup with your output ;)

Comment: Many thanks, @João Dias, that's very clear :) My issue has been perfectly solved!

Comment: @Jingjun, any reason for changing the accepted answer? Is there any problem with my answer that does not solve your issue in any way?

Comment: Just misclick :) Fixed now, sorry @João Dias

Comment: No worries, I was just curious if you still needed help or what my answer was missing ;)

Comment: @Jingjun, feel free to change the accepted answer to the one provided by @ b.GHILAS if you believe his answer is in fact better than mine and helped you more. I am completely fine with it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is that you reuse the `activities` array. The activities array and the ones assigned in the `HashMap` all point to the same reference, so if you update the `activities` array, all the entries in the map will be updated as well.

Assuming the file has the keys ordered, you can tweak your code a little like this

```
HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>> idAndAllActivities = new HashMap<>();
try {
    BufferedReader activityReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(activitiesFile));
    String agentActivity = null;
    ArrayList<String> activities = new ArrayList<>();

    while ((agentActivity = activityReader.readLine()) != null){
          String[] activitySpilted = agentActivity.split(",");
          int activityAgentID = Integer.parseInt(activitySpilted[0]);

          if (activityAgentID == activityRecord){
               activities.add(agentActivity);
          } else {
               idAndAllActivities.put(activityRecord, activities);
               activityRecord = activityAgentID;
               activities = new ArrayList<>();
               activities.add(agentActivity);
          }
     }

     idAndAllActivities.put(activityRecord, activities);

} catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.println(idAndAllActivities);
```

Note that you don't need this: `String activityWithAllInfo = agentActivity;` because `String` is immutable in Java

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Java 8 or higher, the task could be greatly simplified and the code made more readable with the help of `Files.lines` and `Collectors.groupingBy` :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String activitiesFile = "scenarios/BrusselsPopulationFromR/BrusselsActivities.csv";
        Map<Integer,List<String>> idAndAllActivities = null;
        try (Stream<String> content = Files.lines(Paths.get(activitiesFile))) {
            idAndAllActivities = content.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(row -> Integer.parseInt(row.split(",")[0])));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(idAndAllActivities);
    }
}
```